# Display image from Uri in Winrt and MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8, local-storage

So I created an Windows Store app (aka Windows 8 Application / previously called Metro App) and I import a zip archive that contains image (the import work well).

When the zip is exctracted (in it's own folder), I add the object that represent the folder in an ObservableCollection.

This ObservableCollection is used as DataContext to a GridView, the name of the folder is properly displayed but the first image of the folder isn't... <= so that my problem.

I create my object using an static method after the extract is completed

```
public class ZipFolder
    {

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value;}
        }
        public int CurrentPage
        {
            get { return _currentPage; }
            set { _currentPage = value;}
        }
        public Uri PathCover
        {
            get { return _pathCover;  }
            set { _pathCover = value;}
        }

        private string _title ;
        private int _currentPage;
        private Uri _pathCover;

    }
```

```c#
public static async Task<ZipFolderObject> CreateComic(StorageFolder folder)
{
    ZipFolderObject o = new ZipFolderObject();
    o.Title = folder.DisplayName;

    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> asyncOperation = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    StorageFile cover = asyncOperation[0];

    o.PathCover = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + folder.Name + "/" + cover.Name);

    return o;
}
```

And the binding look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="zipFolderItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Width="165" Height="250">
            <Grid Height="215">
                <Border Background="Bisque" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}">
                    <!--<Image x:Name="image" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Cover}" />-->
                    <Image Stretch="Uniform" x:Name="image" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage   UriSource="{Binding PathCover}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Border>
                <Polygon Points="0,0 0,50, 50,0" Stroke="Red" FillRed" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="{Binding CurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource BookmarkVisibilityConverter}}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}" />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="Black" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

So if anyone have the a hint to my problem it'll be great!

Comment: I continue my investigation and I bind directly to the image source a property of a ZipFolder Object of BitmapImage type. It work but I think it could be too much performance consuming and I prefer the first way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be use only directory/filename.ext on Image Source, if extracted images, sub directory.
Concat two value and set to PathCover Property:

```
 folder.Name + "/" + cover.Name
```

And edit Data Templete in this section:

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" x:Name="image" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source={Binding PathCover}/>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use String instead of Uri.

in mainpage.xaml

```
 <Image Source="{Binding VehicleIcon}" Height="54" Width="54"/>
```

in viewmodel.cs file

```
public String VehicleIcon {get;set; }
...
VehicleIcon = "ms-appx:///Assets/logo.png";
```